# Regex for accepting numbers in the range with double precision

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex which will accept numbers in the range 0.00 to 50.00 and also empty space. Double precision is required
**Acceptable format**
.12
0.12
50.00

**Unacceptable format**
.1
0.1
50.1
39

I tried the following

```
^(s*((?:[0-9]|[0-4][0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?$|50(?:\.00?)?))$
```

Comment: Just replace `s*` with `\s*`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex seems to work:

```
^(?:\s*|(?:[0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)\.[0-9]{2})$
```

### Demo

Comment: you need a `\s*` so it can match "also empty space" (I think OP intended to have one at the beginning but left off the \\)

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think just `^\s*(?:...`